Puppeteer is not retaining cookies after setting them with page.setCookie() and closing the browser
I have a puppeteer script that sets the cookies for an authenticated session. Then it closes the browser and reopens it later.
The weird thing is that if I authenticate during the session instead of setting the cookies manually, the second time I open the browser the bot is still logged in.
I'm thinking it might be something related to userDataDir but I am not sure. Anyone knows?

(async () => {
    const browser = await getBrowser();
    const page = await browser.newPage();

      // Set cookies of the page if we have any
      const cookies = readCookiesString();
      if (cookies) {
        const jsonCookies = JSON.parse(cookies) as Cookie[];
        const cleanedCookies = jsonCookies.map(
          ({ name, value, domain, path, expires, httpOnly, secure, sameSite }) => ({
            name,
            value,
            domain,
            path,
            expires,
            httpOnly,
            secure,
            sameSite,
          })
        );

         await page.setCookie(...cleanedCookies);
      }

     // Navigate the page to a URL
      await page.goto(SITE_URL, {
        waitUntil: "domcontentloaded",
        timeout: NETWORK_TIMEOUT,
      });


      await delay(5000);

      await browser.close();
      await delay(5000);

      const browser2 = await getBrowser();
      const page2 = await browser2.newPage();

      await page2.goto(SITE_URL, {
        waitUntil: "domcontentloaded",
        timeout: NETWORK_TIMEOUT,
      });

})()


export const getBrowser = async ({
  noUserData = false,
  headless = false,
  args = [] as string[],
}: Options = {}) => {
  if (browser) {
    return browser;
  }

  const launchParams = {
    headless,
    ...(!!!noUserData && {
      userDataDir: `./src/sessions/userData`,
    }),
    args: [
      `--no-first-run`,
      `--ash-no-nudges`,
      `--no-default-browser-check`,
      ...args,
    ],
  };

  browser = await puppeteer.launch(launchParams);

  return browser;
};




Node: 21.2.0
Puppeteer:
"puppeteer": "^22.8.2",
"puppeteer-extra": "^3.3.6",
"puppeteer-extra-plugin-session": "^1.0.1",
"puppeteer-extra-plugin-stealth": "^2.11.2",
"puppeteer-extra-plugin-user-preferences": "^2.4.1",
I tried the following:

setting cookies with page.setCookie(...args) and with network.send("setCookie", cookies)
I tried manually writing to userDataDir's sqlite but that didn't work either


For whoever needs this in the future. It seems that Chromium saves the session to userDataDir after about 30 seconds or so. If you close the browser before then, userDataDir won't have the cookies you previously set
